# IE Site Navigation Page Flicker

Tags: jquery, css, html, internet-explorer, caching

So I've run into a problem where my pages are flashing upon site navigation. IE, when I click on a link in the header, the page flashes to white briefly before rendering. This only occurs in IE (currently using version 11) whereas it appears to be cached fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Here is a link to the site: [Kelsey's Kreations](http://kelseyskreations.scordesigns.com/flavors).

Here is the code in the head of my pages:

```
<head>
  <title>Flavors - Kelsey's Kreations</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--[if IE]><script>document.createElement('main');</script><![endif]-->

  <script src="http://use.typekit.net/dxe8zqc.js"></script>
  <script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fa.css">

</head>
```

Here is the code at the bottom of my pages:

```
  ...
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/header.js"></script>
</body>
```

I've tried the "Page-Enter" hacks but they appear to have been deprecated as of IE9.

I tried moving the js to the bottom of the page, but the scripts in the head have to remain or else it will cause other problems in all the browsers.

Comment: I am not seeing any flicker. It might possibly be a video card, but doubt it. It might also be your virus scanner interfering with IE, they do crazy things in IE. Check you are not in compatibility mode, you can check this in the F12 tools. Some of your images are on the large side, you might want to optimize those do they download faster. They are loading after the core content renders.

Comment: Mainly it is the svg banner and the header that bothers me the most. When navigating the site on the other browsers, the header remains the same and provides a consistent feel, but on IE it flashes white briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the larger images (1000px cakeballs etc) as a "progressive" jpeg so it gives the appearance of loading faster. This might be enough to get rid of the flicker during load time without the need to change anything else.

If the flicker still won't go away you could put a background color behind it to lessen its effect.

Also take a look here:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/stop-ie-page-load-flicker/

If all else fails, I guess you will join the rest of us that weigh our options when it comes to IE and just let it degrade as nicely as possible.

Comment: No luck. I set the images to progressive and the page is still flickering on IE.